# Capturing HTTP requests for JMeter Raw Data Source

Tags: tcpdump, tshark, jmeter

I'm trying to capture raw http requests for re-playing it later using JMeter and [Raw Data Source](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawDataSource/) plugin. I've tried tshark/tcpdump but it captures the whole TCP data which I dont need, moreover, it cannot save such format to the file, I dont want to use any web server logging plugin to do it, since when you get access to the request data it is usually already parsed by the server, so you have to recreate the raw request which defeats the idea of "rawness". To put it simple, I want to capture HTTP request as they on the wire, before it got parsed or whatever and I want to save it to a file. is it possible? how?

Comment: Umm, tcpdump absolutely *can* save whole packets to a file.

Comment: Thats the problem! PACKETS! I dont need packets, I need pure, raw HTTP part of reassembled packets. It can be done for one request, for example in WireShark, by selecting request, then the HyperText Transfer Protocol part of the request and selecting Copy->Bytes->Printable Only. works for one request, how about 20M?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the use of [WAPT](https://www.loadtestingtool.com/product.shtml). Just use it for the requests you need. You can select a browser, capture the HTTP requests and more.

Then use what you captured and import it in Jmeter. I did it this way, it is quite good.

Note: You don't have to use the Pro version.

Comment: Ah, good for me I dont have to deal with it anymore. But thanks in any case :)

Comment: Alright, this is a bit old. I'm totally in it now, so I thought it could still be interesting to share this. All the best to you.